# laravel is commenting out my view doctype

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

For reasons I don't understand, Laravel seems to be commenting out the doctype tag at the top of my view file:

```
<!--?php<!DOCTYPE html-->
<html lang="en">
```

This is causing the browser to incorrectly render the page.

The view file looks like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ App::getLocale() }}">
```

There is no whitespace above the doctype.

I have confirmed the problem in Safari and Chrome.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem, for anyone interested.

I had a blank api.php file and it caused problems. Adding a comment fixed it.

Comment: Hi, could you be more specific about where I should add a comment, please? Thank you very much